# HBase thrift API very easily got crashed

Tags: hbase, thrift

I usually use python HappyBase API to call Hbase thrift service to save about 100 GB data every day. But I found the thrift services very easily got crashed, almost every day crash once. I looked at the following exception but I didn't find any reasonable info: (Hbase version is 1.2 (Cloudera 5.7) and Happybase version is 0.9)

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.mutateRowsTs(ThriftServerRunner.java:1312)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.mutateRows(ThriftServerRunner.java:1301)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.invoke(HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.java:67)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.mutateRows(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$mutateRows.getResult(Hbase.java:4390)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$mutateRows.getResult(Hbase.java:4374)
            at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
            at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer$ClientConnnection.run(TBoundedThreadPoolServer.java:289)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What HBase version exactly are you using?

Comment: I'm using Hbase1.2 (Cloudera 5.7) and my Happybase version is 0.9

Comment: @Jack the thrift process exit with such error ? it seems related to your data, according to the code, ```rowBatches``` is nil.  can you provide your HappyBase code or reappear this problem with simple scenario ?

Comment: The problem has been fixed, when I increased Thrift JVM memory from 1GB to 6GB. But after a few days I found the Residential Memory become 9GB(saw in Cloudera UI). It looks like Hbase Thrift has some memory leak issue.